# Single word to describe someone who changes topics a lot

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there an adjective that describes a person who changes the subjects a lot? As in, conversation subjects.

EDIT: I found the word "**discursive**" which means to digress from topic to topic. Considering people tend to digress subconsciously this isn't 100% what I was looking for but it will do. Thanks to those who tried helping.

Comment: In a single conversation. Like, the person constantly changes the topic. I already know there's a word for it, I'm just having trouble remembering it.

Comment: I would probably use *motormouth*, but it is not specific to changing subjects.

Comment: Scatterbrain sort of works. **Scattermouth** is out there too with about the meaning you're looking for: http://www.verbotomy.com/verbottle.php?jargonism_id=11991 It doesn't look to have made it into any of the major dictionaries yet.

Comment: Short attention span?

Comment: Sorry, none of these are the words I'm looking for. :/

Comment: Perhaps a "chatterbox" or a person "rambling from one area to the next".

Comment: *digressive* is a word.  *Ramble* and synonyms have some possibilities

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat broader term that might suit, depending on the circumstances, is *[flibbertigibbet](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/flibbertigibbet)*

> A frivolous, flighty, or excessively talkative person.

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Also, the term *[scattershot](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=scattershot)* could be applied to the discourse (but not the person)

> Covering a wide range in a random way; indiscriminate: "his habit of scattershot comment on whatever issue catches his eye" (Howell Raines).

*American Heritage Dictionary*

Answer (score 0):

Flighty? Unfocused? Undisciplined? To some extent it depends on the kind of conversation; I'd only use "undisciplined" if the discussion was professional.

Comment: The person is intentionally changing the conversation. It's not done out of a lack of responses, confusion or an act of subconsciousness, it's just something they do a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a single word, but the correct term for switching from topic to topic or being unable stay on topic is:

> poor topic maintenance

"she had poor topic maintenance" is correct.

This is something I commonly see as a speech language pathologist; it is considered a pragmatic language deficit.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, adhd/add.  You could just use attention deficient.  Maybe just pull the person aside and mention this tendency and suggest they talk to a doctor about it.